# Tell Vim's put to print a string at a position given by the value of a variable

Tags: vimscript, variables

I would like to add a new line in a certain line in a buffer. So far my starting position is as follows:

```
let newl = "\n"
" set cursor to beginning of buffer
call cursor(1,1)
" search up to 10 lines down
search("somestring",'',10)
" get the line number of the match
let cursor_pos = getpos(".")
let cursor_line = cursor_pos[1]
" put a newline directly behind it
(cursor_line+1)put =newl
```

Now, I cannot combine a variable with `put` like I would with a number: `11put`. How can I accomplish that?

The second problem is rather of a aesthetic nature: When using something like `11put ="\n"` Vim behaves weird, it somehow prints out a value of a variable that has nothing to do with a newline.

Is there a way to get the task done in an overall better way - putting a newline at a certain position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
/somestring
normal! o
```

If you want to have it dynamic, take a look at `:exe`.

Or:

```
:call append(cursor_line, '')
```

Comment: I think `execute` is what he's getting at. An example that might work for you: `exe (cursor_line+1) . "put = newl"`

Comment: That example did help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the blackhole register, `"_` with `:put`

```
:99put_
```

Or use an expression register, `"=`, with an array of empty strings:

```
:99put=['']
:99put=repeat([''], 3)
```

If you want to put a specific string on a line:

```
:let str = 'hello world'
:99put=str
```

Comment: Interessting those register. <Falling into a blackhole about `:help registers`> ;-). So many things to see and learn...